# How to recode the algorithm to speed up the program in Matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a problem with this code below. In this algorithm I would like to delete the noise peaks from the EMG signal. My problem is the running time of this program. It lasts a couple of minutes, so I can't do this algoritm for many signals. I'd like to add, that I'm begginer user of  Matlab. I tried to rewrite this code many hours, but I failed.

```
y=xlsread('D:\myfile\', 'Sheet1', 'B:B');
x=abs(y);
c=max(x);
for n=2:length(y1); % delete the peaks of the signal
    z(n)=x(n)-x(n-1);
    if z(n)>=0.3*c;
        k=0; m=1;
        while (x(n-m)<x(n-k));
            m=m+1;
            k=k+1;
        end
        m=m-1;
        while (m>0);
            x(n-m)=0;
            m=m-1;
        end
        p=0; r=1;
        while (x(n+p)<x(n+r)); %count values, which increase to the right of   x(n)
            p=p+1;
            r=r+1;
        end
        o=n+p;
        r=r-2;
        j=n+r;
        while (j>n); %reset values, which increase to the right of x(n)
            x(j)=0;
            j=j-1;
        end
        i=1; j=0;
        while (x(o+i)<x(o+j));
            i=i+1;
            j=j+1;
        end
        i=i-1;
        while (i>0);
            x(o+i)=0;
            i=i-1;
        end
        x(o)=0;
        x(n)=0;
    end
    x(1)=0;
    x(2)=0;
    plot(u,y1,'.');
    hold on
    title('signal without noise')
    ylabel 'mV'
end
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation: in the Matlab editor, select all text (CTRL+A) and then press CTRL+I to automatically indent your code. Please edit your question with the resulting, nicely indented code, I will not have a look at it before you do that ...

Comment: I try to do this as you write. Is it ok?

Comment: No, it still looks horrible, you didn't do what I said. The stuff that goes between the `while` and the corresponding `end` should be indented by 4 spaces more. Matlab does this for you automatically ...

Comment: And what is `y1` equal to?

Comment: @calleigh At first glance it appears that you can vectorize your code quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The key to speeding up any code is to first run it in a profiler, and and see what takes so long about it. To do so, try this:

```
profile on
% Put your code here
profile viewer
profile off
```

As for your specific code, I would take a look at the `filter2` function, which I believe will do a lot of the kinds of things you are doing, only a lot quicker. Check out the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html) on the subject.